# Using mmap to read/write Registers

Tags: c++, mmap

I am trying to learn the use of mmap to read and write some registers.  I have the following code.

```
#define MY_BASE_ADDRESS  0xC0000000 //Base Address for the PCIe
#define LED_ADDRESS      0x00010000 //Offset for LEDS  0x00010000
#define MAPPED_FILE_SIZE  (50 * sizeof(int)) //Guess
#define PAGE_SIZE (sysconf( _SC_PAGESIZE));

void *mapped_region, *mapped_LED_base;

off_t dev_base = (  MY_BASE_ADDRESS | LED_ADDRESS);
unsigned long readback = 0;
```

First I open the /dev/mem

```
//The O_SYNC option prevents Linux from caching the contents of /dev/mem
memoryFileDescriptor = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR | O_SYNC);
    if (memoryFileDescriptor == -1)
        {
        printf("Can't open /dev/mem. %d\n", memoryFileDescriptor );
        exit(0);
        }

// Map one page of memory into user space such that the device is in that page, but  
//it    may not
// be at the start of the page.
mapped_region = mmap(NULL,
                    MAPPED_FILE_SIZE,  //How to know size?
                    PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                    MAP_SHARED,  //File may not be updated until msync or munmap is 
                                                                          // called.
                    memoryFileDescriptor,
                    dev_base);  //How to know the offset?

// get the address of the device in user space which will be an offset from the base
// that was mapped as memory is mapped at the start of a page
mapped_LED_base = mapped_region + dev_base;
```

Then I will write to the address:

```
*((volatile unsigned long *) (mapped_LED_base)) = 0xFFFFF;
```

And Read

```
readback = *((volatile unsigned long *) (mapped_LED_base));
```

I am having trouble knowing what is the MAP_SIZE and its offset?  The documentation was not so clear on that.  The current code gives a segmentation fault error.

I am using Linux and C++

Answer (score 0):

The size is the size of your hardware's registers, so currently you are saying that you have 50 x 32 bit registers. In practice, this number is rounded up to the page-size of the architecture, typically 4KB.

If you have only one register that is unsigned long, then you should set it to `sizeof(unsigned long)` - you should not map more than you actually need - even if the system "grows" this to 4KB.

Comment: Is dev_base, the offset correct?  This means the address where the mmap will start?

Comment: Address within the file where your mapping starts, yes. Have you actually checked that your pointer that you get back from mmap is not -1 (meaning error)?

Comment: Yes, mmap does not return -1.  So, I open dev/mem and start my mapping at the address dev_base for 50*ints length.  That address is correct, don't know why it crashes.